# Can i divide the models in different files in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Currently all my models are in models.py. Ist becomming very messy.
Can i have the separate file like  `base_models.py` so that i put my main models there which i don't want to touch

Also same case for views and put in separate folder rather than develop a new app

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's doable. It's not particularly pretty though:

make models a module, so your directory structure looks like this:

```
- models
|- __init__.py
|- some_model.py
|- some_other_model.py
|- ...
```

now, the magic lies in `__init__.py` and some little extras in the models. `__init__.py`:

```
from some_model import SomeModel
from some_other_model import SomeOtherModel

__all__ = [ 
    'SomeModel',
    'SomeOtherModel',
]
```

some_model.py:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    class Meta(object):
        app_label = 'yourapplabel'
        db_table = 'yourapplabel_somemodel'
```

Comment: thanks for the underscores acjohnson55, it was a little early in the morning

Comment: from .some_model import SomeModel // For me it works when i use .(dot)

Comment: How do you deal with circular imports then?

Answer (score 2):

Everything acjohnson55 said, plus the fact that you need to specify the app_label attribute in each model's Meta class.

A link to an actual example on github:
https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer/tree/develop/filer/models

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just make a folder called `models` and in that folder put all of your separated model files.  You need to put a file called `__init__.py` in the `models` folder for it to be considered the `models` module.  In `__init__.py`, use `from ... import ...` to put the names you want available directly in `yourapp.models`, otherwise you will have to import them as `yourapp.models.base_model`, or whatever submodule name you use.

Also, in each model, you will have to add a Meta attribute called [`app_label = 'yourapp'`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label) to make sure your models are recognized as part of the app.

Answer (score 0):

you can separate the model file like this :
-------models/
 
-------------- **init**.py 
-------------- usermodels.py 
--------------othermodel.py

in the **init**.py:
---------------from usermodels import * 
---------------from othermodel import * 
and in the *models.py  , add META class:
--------class Meta: 
--------------app_label = 'appName'

Answer (score 0):

This is how I normally do it:

```
# Folder structure:
#==================
# models/
#   __init__.py
#   products.py
#   stocks.py

# In init.py (don't forget the period before model file name)
#===========
from .products import Product
from .stocks import Stock

__all__ = [
    'Product',
    'Stock',
]

# And run "py manage.py makemigrations" and "py manage.py migrate" as normal
```