# Create Models in other than models.py files (Django-Wiki)

Tags: python, django, django-models, wiki

I am using Django wiki module in my project , IN wiki module models are created in their different files.Structure are as follows.

```
models/
   article.py
   abcd.py
   ...
   __init.py__
```

Now I want to add some new models into article.py but after creating models when I try to migrate them I am getting the message , **Nothing seems to change**. However If I change any field of existing model then migration catch the change.

My init.py files imports all models of articles.py , So I think migration must have created the models but It doesn't . so can anyone tell me where I am wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use south for migration?

Comment: @glasslion yes , I am using south

Comment: Have you added a `class Meta: app_label = settings.APP_LABEL` to your new models?  Perhaps show an example model class that you've added.

Comment: You should take a look at the answers to this question: [can-i-divide-the-models-in-different-files-in-django][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718656/can-i-divide-the-models-in-different-files-in-django